# Is there any algorithm to split multistatement query by semicolon?

Tags: java, sql

Queries syntax differ depending on the database carrier.

For example Teradata flavor String :

```
  String sql =  "   SEL *  FROM db.test;  " + 
                  "   SEL 'test;test'  FROM db.test " ;
```

This `String sql` contains two queries split with a semicolon. However `String [] sqls = sql.split(";");` will not work because there is an additional semicolon within the character string `test;test`

Other databases might have more complex and more tricky examples. Is there any algorithm that works for every database, and able to parse a multi statement query?

Comment: *"Is there any algorithm"*? Yes. A SQL parser. Now you just need to write it. Or search the web to see if one is already written and accessible to you.

Comment: Given JDBC is not officially supporting multi-statement query, why would you have such sql string from beginning?

Comment: Assume that there *is* an algorithm, try something, and ask about that if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Well your input is ambiguous. But if it's just select statements, you will be using. You can develop below code to get desired result.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sql =  "   SELECT *  FROM db.test;  " +
                "   SELECT 'test;test'  FROM db.test " ;

        String[] sqldata = sql.trim().split("[ ]{1,10}");

        ArrayList data = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(sqldata));

        ArrayList<StringBuilder> modifiedSql = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
        int i = 0;
        String previous = new String();
        for (Object str: data) {
            String d_ex = (String) str;
            if ( d_ex.matches("select|SELECT") ) {
                if( previous.matches(".*;") && i != 0){
                    System.out.println(previous);
                    i++;
                    modifiedSql.add(i, modifiedSql.get(i).append(" "+d_ex) );
                }
                if( i == 0) {
                    modifiedSql.add(i,new StringBuilder(" "+d_ex));
                }else modifiedSql.set(i,modifiedSql.get(i).append(" "+d_ex));
            } else modifiedSql.set(i,modifiedSql.get(i).append(" "+d_ex));
            previous = d_ex;
        }

        modifiedSql.stream().forEach((d)-> System.out.println(d));
    }
}
```